# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i made a function appendScript which will be called on a button click event my function code is

```
function appendScript()
{
    var v_js;
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    v_js = document.createElement('script');
    v_js.type = 'text/javascript';
    v_js.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js";
    head.appendChild(v_js);

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    v_js =document.createElement('script');
    v_js.type="text/javascript" ;
    v_js.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js";

    body.appendChild(v_js);
    var v_css = document.createElement('link');

    body.appendChild(v_css);

    interval=self.setInterval(function(){  if(jQuery && typeof $().modal ==  'function')
        {

            window.clearInterval(interval);

            //create a div in the body which we will use for our dialog.
            $(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).append('<div id="myModal"  class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"   aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>One fine body…</p></div><div  class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');

            $('#myModal').modal('show')
            //setTimeout is non blocking (basically async) so lets put our apex call in a timeout so it doesn't
            //stop our dialog from showing.

         }

    }
,300);                           

}
```

and the error i am facing is

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Comment: Maybe Bootstrap is loaded before jQuery; Set bootstrap script initialization as a function in jQuery's event `onload`. Also try separate variable name `v_js` for jQuery and Bootstrap (it's probably not cause of this problem but just to be sure).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your code.
I made simple fiddle in which your code works.

Are you sure you are using the lastest jQuery version?

You should try the debugversion of bootstrap to get more information about what is undefined.

```
 Working sample
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYzzP/)

Answer (score -1):

Exactly am also face this problem.There no problem in your code..you try to load the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css this only fire a issue like undefined function in bootstrap.If you remove anyone of the bootstrap file. the error will be cleared.